# How to extract a dbschema from a dacpac

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, database-schema, dacpac

I upgraded my database project from VS2010 to VS2012. The problem is that I was using the generated dbschema to automatically create wrappers on the stored procedures.
How can I get a dbschema from the updated database project (or from the generated .dacpac)?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe it is useful for you: http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2013/02/11/database-schema-synchronization-with-sql-server-data-tools/ and http://sqlzapper.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/database-projects-using-sql-data-tools/ .

Comment: Please add the actual answer